# Can "online German course" be a valid response for "Wo studieren Sie?"?

Tags: standard-german

For an A2 German speaking exam, with the topic "Studium", if the question asked is "Wo studieren Sie", can the response be
"I am doing an online German course" - "Ich mache einen Online-Deutschkurs."?
or does the response need to be a more formal "Studium" like College/University/degree?

Answer (score 1):

"Studium" - when related to formal education - is exclusively use for College/University degree acquisition. You wouldn't use that for non-formal training or online courses.

There is a second meaning of "Studium" which simply means "reading", but that does not apply here.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, someone asking for where someone studys in the sense of "studieren" expects the answer to be a university/"college".

However, the term "Selbststudium" is used for autididactic learning outside of a formal education like in a university.

But the place of a "Selbststudium" does not have to be asked for, as it is clear that it happens at what someone considers his home.

Then again, "where do you study" could ask for the place - usually the city - or the university. Only answering with the place would interpret the question very literally. Most of the time, the answer would include the name of university, and if there is a worry of confusion, optionally the location (city) as well.

The preposition "an" with Dativ case is used for the university, and "in" with Dativ case is used for the location of the university.
Here is an example:

> Ich studiere **an der Max-Mustermann-Universität** in Hamburg.

Comment: Thank you!
So if one asks "Wo studieren Sie?" do the responses below sound natural:
I am not studying now - Ich studiere jetzt nicht.
I finished my studies in 2001 - I habe mein Studium im 2001 Jahr abgeschlossen.

Comment: @ur22coolz "jetzt" is very situational (?), you should consider an adverb like "derzeit" or "zurzeit". Otherwise, it sounds fine to me.